# Python - which encoding should be applied to a string to be passed to hashlib.sha256()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding

First I used this function in a pyspark udf and it worked correctly

```
def encrypt_hash_col_value(column):
    sha_value = hashlib.sha256(column.encode()).hexdigest()
    return sha_value

spark_udf = udf(encrypt_hash_col_value, StringType())

df_hashed = df.withColumn("metric_1", spark_udf("metric_1"))
```

However with `pandas_udf` first I got an error:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'`
I fixed this by modifying the line `hashlib.sha256(column.str.encode()).hexdigest()`.

But now it's failing with `TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'encoding'`. What encoding should be added as an argument to column.str.encode() in this case?

When I use column.str.encode("UTF-8"), getting this error: `TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required`

Comment: `hashlib.sha256` requires a `bytes` object. You can't pass it a `pandas.Series` object. The encoding is *whatever you choose*. There is not "right" encoding.

Comment: What does "it's not working mean" **exactly*? *Again you can't pass a series to that function*. You have to apply that function to each object in your series, and they have to be `bytes` objects (or objects that support the buffer protocol...). It is not clear what you are tryin to accomplish at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it will be great if you suggest how to use this function with `pandas_udf`